# How to calculate kinetic energy on a trajectory?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, potential

I've got this weirdly formulated task, that I try to solve: Given a curve $\gamma$ parametrised by $\eta$ where

$x = \dfrac{p}{2}\,(1-\eta^2), \quad y = p\,\eta,\quad t = \sqrt{\dfrac{m\,p^3}{a}}\,\dfrac{\eta}{2}\,\left(1+\dfrac{\eta^2}{3}\right)$.

I really don't grasp why they named the last coordinate after $t$ but I took it to mean $\gamma(\eta) = \left(\begin{array}{cc}x(\eta)\\y(\eta)\\t(\eta)\end{array}\right)$.

The goal is to calculate the kinetic energy on the curve, moving through a force field $F = -\dfrac{a}{|r|^3}\,r$ what I interpreted as $F =-\dfrac{a}{\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}} \left(\begin{array}{c}x\\y\\z\end{array}\right)$.

How am I supposed to calculate that? I know work is defined as $W = \int F\,\mathrm{ds}$. In that case $\displaystyle W = \Delta E = \int F(\gamma(\eta))\,\gamma'(\eta)\,\mathrm{d\eta}$. But do I really need to evaluate the whole integral? Alternatively I could evaluate $\Delta E = \phi(\gamma(\eta_1))-\phi(\gamma(\eta_2))$ since a potential does exist: $\phi = \dfrac{a}{|r|}$. But for what starting and ending point $\eta_1\,\eta_2$ ? And how do I deduce the kinetic energie from there?

Also in the next task I am required to find the potential energy. Not having a clue how to put it together.

---

**Edits**

According to another interpretation, $t$ is symbolising the time. Velocity has to be calculated individually by differentiating with respect to $t$. For instance velocity in $x$-direction should be:

$$v_x = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} = \dfrac{\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d} \eta}{\mathrm{d}t/\mathrm{d}\eta} = \dfrac{-4\,c_2\,\eta}{c_1\left(1+\eta^2\right)}$$ where $c_1 = \sqrt{\frac{m\,p^3}{a}}$ and $c_2 = \frac{p}{2}$

How to go on whatsoever? Finding a potential $V$ in order to calculate potential energy seems improbable since $\Delta V = -F\,\ddot{\vec{r}}$, however $\dfrac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{dt}^2} = \dfrac{\dfrac{\mathrm{d}^2r}{\mathrm{d\eta}^2}\,\dfrac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d\eta}}-\dfrac{\mathrm{d^2}t}{\mathrm{d\eta}^2}\,\dfrac{\mathrm{d}r}{\mathrm{d\eta}}}{\left(\dfrac{\mathrm{d}t}{\mathrm{d\eta}}\right)^3}$ really bulky

Answer (score 1):

Here is a conceptual outline. Motion is in the x,y plane. Given a value of $\eta$, you can calculate where it is. t is the time when $\eta$ has that value. Given a value of $\eta$, you can calculate the time.

Given t, x, and y, you can calculate the velocity and from that the kinetic energy.

Comment: Thank you for your outline. So quickly trying to summarise what you are saying: $\gamma(t)$ is given by $\left(\begin{array}{c}x(\eta(t))\\y(\eta(t))\end{array}\right)$ So I need to find $t^{-1}(\eta)$ plug it in and derive with respect to $t$ to get the velocity? But don't I need to take the Force field into account? Secondly, how do I calculate potential energy if motion is just restricted to $x$-$y$-$\text{plane}$ ?

Comment: You were given $t(\eta)$, not $\eta(t)$. You want kinetic energy, which is $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$, where $v_x = dx(\eta)/dt(\eta)$ and $dv_y$ is similar. You will have to play with calculus to figure out how to do the derivatives.

Comment: Alright, but how do I combine those components of derivatives/ kinetic energies? (look **Edits**). Taking the absolute value? Also, still unclear what the total potential energy be like. $0$ because motion just happens in the $x$-$y$-plane?